# How to generate array with specific sum of his elements in c#?

Tags: c#

How to generate array with specific sum of elements? Does exist such an algorithm?

I try something like this:

```
        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        string serial = "";

        int chekSumBlockOne = 280;
        int checkSumBlockOne_tmp = 0;
        var blockOne = new char[4];

        var random = new Random();
        while (chekSumBlockOne != checkSumBlockOne_tmp)
        {
            checkSumBlockOne_tmp = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < blockOne.Length; i++)
            {
                blockOne[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
            }

            foreach (char symbol in blockOne)
            {
                checkSumBlockOne_tmp += (int)symbol;
            }

        }
```

but my method is very slow.

Comment: [Subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

Comment: what is is your actual requirement? what you are expecting

Comment: I think `Random` is a bad approach. Just start with 'AAAA' and calculate the sum, then change the characters base on the difference between `chekSumBlockOne ` and the sum

Comment: Certainly using random for *all* elements is a bad idea. One (obvious) improvement is to randomly generate all but one element. Then compute the difference between the desired sum and the current one. If that difference represents a member of the original set, that's the only value you can use to complete your subset and achieve your desired goal.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: You are correct, I have posted an answer based on this

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination and search _.net all combination_ in search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As like others comment, Random will not be a better option here. I Suggest You to Iterate from 1 (if the value is sum is less than `100`) to Some `N` and take All combination of characters in each level and compare there value with the given sum. break the loop once you got any Possible string. Here is an example For you:

```
var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
int chekSumBlockOne = 280;
List<string> possibleOutComes = new List<string>();
var qw = chars.Select(x => x.ToString());
int numberOfChars = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChars; i++)
{
    qw = qw.SelectMany(x => chars, (x, y) => x + y);
    possibleOutComes = qw.Where(x => x.Sum(y => (int)y) == chekSumBlockOne).ToList();
    if (possibleOutComes.Count > 0)
        break;
}
```

In this case you will get 24391 combinations(**string contains 4 characters @ i=3**) that satisfies the condition. Some of them are follows:

```
AAAU
AABT
AACS
```

Comment: Minor detail: I would choose to rename `numberOfCombinations` to `numberOfChars`. and do `int numberOfChars = 4;` makes `for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChars; i++)` because the value in `numberOfCombinations` is invalid to what the variable declares.

Comment: Nice solution, `qw = qw.SelectMany(x => chars, (x, y) => x + y);` is hard to follow this line of code.. I made one also.. _(just for fun)_

Answer (score 0):

See code below.  Generating 3 random number and then filling in last number reduces time significantly.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication102
{
    class Program
    {
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //65 to 90 and 48 to 57
            var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            string serial = "";

            int chekSumBlockOne = 280;
            int minChar = chekSumBlockOne - 90;
            int maxChar = chekSumBlockOne - 65;
            int minInt = chekSumBlockOne - 57;
            int maxInt = chekSumBlockOne - 48;

            int checkSumBlockOne_tmp = 0;
            var blockOne = new char[4];

            var random = new Random();
            Boolean done = false;
            while (!done)
            {
                checkSumBlockOne_tmp = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < blockOne.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    int rand = random.Next(chars.Length);
                    blockOne[i] = chars[rand];
                    checkSumBlockOne_tmp += (int)blockOne[i];
                }
                if ((checkSumBlockOne_tmp >= minChar) && (checkSumBlockOne_tmp <= maxChar))
                {
                    blockOne[blockOne.Length - 1] = chars[(chekSumBlockOne - checkSumBlockOne_tmp) - 65];
                    break;
                }
                if ((checkSumBlockOne_tmp >= minInt) && (checkSumBlockOne_tmp <= maxInt))
                {
                    blockOne[blockOne.Length - 1] = chars[((chekSumBlockOne = checkSumBlockOne_tmp) - 65) + 26];
                    break;
                }
            }

 
        }
 
    }


 
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same results as un-lucky (+1):

I did some Enumerable magic to..  *(outside the KISS principle)*

```
private static IEnumerable<string> EnumCombinations(int checkSumBlockOne, int numberOfChars)
{
    // i did swap the numbers to the front, this way it will always be chronological.
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToArray();
    var charValues = chars.Select(c => (int)c).ToArray();
    var digitValue = Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfChars).Select(i => (long)Math.Pow(charValues.Length, i)).ToArray();

    var totalIterations = (long)Math.Pow(chars.Length, numberOfChars);

    long index = 0;

    while (index <= totalIterations)
    {
        if (checkSumBlockOne == Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfChars).Sum(i => charValues[(index / digitValue[i]) % charValues.Length]))
            yield return new string(Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfChars).Select(i => chars[(index / digitValue[i]) % charValues.Length]).ToArray());

        index++;
    }
}
```

---

```
Trace.WriteLine(EnumCombinations(280, 4).Count());
Trace.WriteLine("");
foreach (var combi in EnumCombinations(280, 4).Take(10))
{
    Trace.WriteLine(combi);
}
```

---

results:

```
24391

04ZZ
13ZZ
22ZZ
31ZZ
40ZZ
05YZ
14YZ
23YZ
32YZ
41YZ
```

The idea of this code is, that i handle index as a base 36 number system. With division and modulo i get the chars indices.